# HP DL380 G7 Power Calculation

Tags: hp, power-supply-unit

My current Config

> HP DL380 G7
>
> 2x E5620 CPU (80 W each)
>
> 8x 16 GB 1000 MHZ DDR3 Ram
>
> 4x Sata SSD
>
> Dual 460 W Power supply.

### Can I replace cpu's with Dual X5675 (95 W each) ?

HP Power Advisor tool says that i can.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0UlH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. As long as you use the official upgrade kits, even the support for this machine will continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: i was planning to replace cpus and add fans and heatsink to it. i believe kits have same components too. did i missed anything else ?

Comment: Yes, the kits do include heatsinks, power cards (depending on the upgrade) and missing fans. No, I don't think you are missing anything else.